# build bitwise OR string from array for SSL crypto constants in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app that uses a separate configuration file for options that a user might want to set on their own. Recently I was asked to include the ability to define TLS settings. I would like my configuration file to have an array variable that allows the user to input the desired crypto constants and have my app take that array variable and build a bitwise OR string for the server instance. The following is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. In practice 'httpsOpts' will be in a separate file, but that's not relevant for the example. How would I go about achieved the desired result?

```
const https = require('https');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const express = require('express');

const sslOpts = ['SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1','SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1'];
let httpsOpts = {};

httpsOpts.secureOptions = ''; // build the following: crypto.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | crypto.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1

const app = express();
const webServer = https.createServer(httpsOpts, app);
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with encase anyone else has the same issue. I'm sure there are better answers since this involves the dreaded 'eval' but it's what I got for now.

```
let _opts = '';
sslOpts.forEach((v,i) => {
    _opts+='crypto.constants.'+v;
    if (i < sslOpts.length-1) _opts+=' | ';
});
httpsOpts.secureOptions = eval(_opts);
```